# pg_basebackup does not copy any data / checkpoint is empty

Tags: postgresql

I have a 100GB database that I want to replicate.

On the target server I'm running:

```
sudo -iu postgres PGPASSWORD=xxx pg_basebackup -v -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main -U postgres -X fetch -P -h source.host.com -p 5432
pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 3/5000028 on timeline 1
70435/70435 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace                                         
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log end point: 3/5000100
pg_basebackup: syncing data to disk ...
pg_basebackup: renaming backup_manifest.tmp to backup_manifest
pg_basebackup: base backup completed
```

Exit code is 0. But no data is copied. Targets `/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/base` is virtually empty, and 100GB on the source:

```
target:/var/lib/postgresql/14/main# du -d1 -h
16M ./pg_wal
540K    ./global
0   ./pg_commit_ts
0   ./pg_dynshmem
0   ./pg_notify
0   ./pg_serial
0   ./pg_snapshots
0   ./pg_subtrans
0   ./pg_twophase
16K ./pg_multixact
52M ./base
0   ./pg_replslot
0   ./pg_tblspc
0   ./pg_stat
0   ./pg_stat_tmp
8.0K    ./pg_xact
4.0K    ./pg_logical
69M .
```

```
source:/var/lib/postgresql/14/main# du -d1 -h
785M    ./pg_wal
564K    ./global
0   ./pg_commit_ts
0   ./pg_dynshmem
0   ./pg_notify
0   ./pg_serial
0   ./pg_snapshots
96K ./pg_subtrans
0   ./pg_twophase
16K ./pg_multixact
92G ./base
0   ./pg_replslot
0   ./pg_tblspc
0   ./pg_stat
72K ./pg_stat_tmp
8.0K    ./pg_xact
4.0K    ./pg_logical
92G .
```

Target is missing a bunch of 1GB files named `/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/base/19399/13633xx.yy`. All subdirs of base are the same though.

Logs on the source say:

```
source postgres[1658348]: [10-1]   LOG:  checkpoint starting: force wait
source postgres[1658348]: [11-1]   LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.007 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.022 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s; distance=16383 kB, estimate=16384 kB
```

Running `pg_basebackup` locally in the source works fine.

Both servers running postgres 14.

What could be going on?

Comment: If it completes without error, it should be good. What do you mean "virtually empty"? Please be specific. Is there a copy of the data directory or not? How do you measure the disk usage?

Comment: Try to identify which files are missing in the `base` directory.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 2nd edit

Comment: Are you sure those are the exact names of the files? PostgreSQL doesn't have such files. Also, what was the return code from `pg_basebackup`?

Comment: Missed a subdir. xx.yy are ofc placeholders for numbers. Missing file is eg. /var/lib/postgresql/14/main/base/19399/1363366.85. Exit code 0.

Comment: The files belong to the PostgreSQL user and have normal permissions? No idea...

Comment: Yes and yes. Super strange :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246221/discussion-between-abaelter-and-laurenz-albe).

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that most tables are [UNLOGGED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-createtable.html#id=SQL-CREATETABLE-UNLOGGED) tables. Those are not included in checkpoints.